# How to determine how much data was sent through a TLS/TCP OutputStream on Android?

Tags: android, sockets, ssl, tcp

The point is really this - my Android TLS/TCP socket disconnects sometimes mid-data stream. Usually because of timeouts, etc. I'm trying to determine how much data was actually sent successfully BEFORE the socket cut off so I know where to pick up.

How do I do this?

My thought is to pull the output stream from the socket and write a little bit at a time. If we get a disconnect then I can pick up where we left off and continue sending the next chunk.

I chose NOT to use a BufferedOutputStream because after the disconnect I wouldn't be sure how much was sent and how much wasn't. I'd love to be mistaken.

This is my best attempt:

```java
/**
 * Static class that holds the currently writable data
 */
final private class WritingByteArray {
    /**
     * Easy C-tor
     */
    public WritingByteArray( final byte[] bytes ) {
        this.bytes = bytes;
        this.offset = 0;
    }

    /**
     * Convenience
     */
    public int length() {
        return( bytes.length );
    }

    /**
     * Convenience
     */
    public int remaining( int max ) {
        return( Math.min( max, length()-offset ) );
    }

    /**
     * Consume bytes. Really just increment the offset with a safety catch
     */
    private void consume( int size ) {
        offset = Math.min( bytes.length, offset+size );
    }

    /**
     * Remaining without a max
     */
    public int remaining() {
        return( length()-offset );
    }

    /**
     * Are we empty?
     */
    public boolean empty() {
        return( offset>=length() );
    }

    public byte[] bytes; //!< The byte array we're working with
    public int offset; //!< Our reading offset
}

/**
 * Our write data function new
 */
private void writeDataNew() {
    final int WRITE_BUFFER_SIZE = ( 8*1024 ); //!< 8kb of write buffer size

    try {
        OutputStream outputStream = sslSocket.getOutputStream();

        // Do we have data we are currently writing
        if( currentByteArray==null ) {
            Log.d(
                    TAG,
                    "We don't have anything in the current byte array. Pulling from the output buffer."
                 );

            // Pull from the outputBuffer
            synchronized( outputBuffer ) {
                final int size = outputBuffer.size();

                Log.d( TAG, "OutputBuffer has "+size );

                // This was one done outside of synchronization... that's bad!
                if( size==0 ) {
                    Log.d( TAG, "Our output buffer is actually empty." );
                    return;
                }

                // Copy the bytes to our private byte array
                currentByteArray = new WritingByteArray( outputBuffer.toByteArray() );

                // Get the data
                //                    outputStream.write( outputBuffer.toByteArray() );
                // Reset the buffer
                outputBuffer.reset();
            } // Free the mutex so bytearray can be written again
        }

        // Now write the data
        final int size = currentByteArray.remaining( WRITE_BUFFER_SIZE );

        // Do we have bytes to send?
        if( size>0 ) {
            // Alert how much we'll write
            Log.d( TAG, "We have "+size+" data to write" );
            // Write our deduced size
            outputStream.write( currentByteArray.bytes, currentByteArray.offset, size );
            // Flush the output so we can block???
            // DOES THIS BLOCK?
            // If this blocks maybe this will work...
            outputStream.flush();
            // Just a log tag
            Log.d( TAG, "Data wrote "+size+" bytes of data." );

            // Now consume
            currentByteArray.consume( size );

            // Do we have any left?
            if( currentByteArray.empty() ) {
                Log.d( TAG, "Clearing currentByteArray" );

                currentByteArray = null; // Clear it so we know
            }
        }
        else {
            Log.d( TAG, "No more data left " );
            // Just in case
            currentByteArray = null;
        }

        // Call again
        writeDataNew();
    }
    catch( final Exception e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        reportError( e.getLocalizedMessage() );

        // Here we can reconnect and send more data if we failed out
    }
}
```

Comment: Define "sent successfully". Does that mean, "received by the peer", or "queued to the OS for transmission"?

Comment: That's a good question. I'm rooting for "received by the peer" but that might not be knowable I'm thinking unless I ask the peer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Information about how much data has been received by the peer is essentially unrecoverable (when discussion is limited to the TCP protocol itself). IOW: You can't do what you're trying to do just by modifying the client.

Yes, [TCP](https://images.app.goo.gl/HsDvTu8QhC9XY4D3A) does include bidirectional ACKs that include information on how much data has been successfully transferred, but that information is not directly available to the application layer.

Even if you could access the TCP ACK information, there's no way to know that you've *received* every ACK the peer *sent*, at the moment a connection fails. (See: [Two General's Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Generals%27_Problem).)

Note that even if you don't use a `BufferedOutputStream`, buffering still occurs in the TLS layer, and at multiple network layers, including within the kernel.

Bottom line: It is impossible to know the peer's "receive" state with 100% certainty, unless this information is explicitly transmitted, or both peers have some way of agreeing on a common "ground" state that exists at the moment a connection begins.

Most practical systems will have the client query for the peer's state at the beginning of a conversation (`HTTP HEAD`, as an example), or they'll keep track of explicit acknowledgements sent by the peer. Note that even an orderly connection close can serve as an explicit acknowledgement.

Comment: PS I think this answer is fantastic.